# How to eleminate the duplicate objects within the array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, filter, es6-map

I am trying to filter the duplicate values and get the unique values as an array of object. I don't know how to get the unique value based on the color. so below is my data:

```
[
    {
        "code": "xxxx1",
     
        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 649.99
        },
 
        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#212028 |Black",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "xx2",
        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 999.99
        },

        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#212028 |Black",
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "xx3",
        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 549.99
        },
        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#D3CCC1 |Silver",
            },
           
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "xxx-4",

        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 649.99
        },
   
        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#D3CCC1 |Silver",
               
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected Value is:

```
[
    {
        "code": "xxxx1",
     
        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 649.99
        },
 
        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#212028 |Black",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "xx3",
        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 549.99
        },
        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#D3CCC1 |Silver",
            },
           
        ]
    },
   
]
```

The below code returns only the variants array of objects. but I want as an expected result which I mentioned as above

```
  let variants2 = Array.from(
            new Set(
              variants.map(
                (a) => a.variants
              )
            )
          ).map((variants) => {
            return variants.find((a) => a.color=== a.color);
          });
          [
            ...new Map(variants2.map((item) => [item.value, item])).values(),
          ];
```

can someone help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: Please state what is the difference between `data` and `expected value`. The code is long and irrelevant to the solution / question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the many possible approaches (the input array is called `items`):

```js
Array.from(new Map(items.reverse().map(item => [item.variants[0].color, item])).values()).reverse();
```

Test:

```js
const items = [
    {
        "code": "xxxx1",
     
        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 649.99
        },
 
        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#212028 |Black",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "xx2",
        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 999.99
        },

        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#212028 |Black",
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "xx3",
        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 549.99
        },
        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#D3CCC1 |Silver",
            },
           
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "xxx-4",

        "priceData": {
            "currencyIso": "USD",
            "value": 649.99
        },
   
        "variants": [
            {
                "color": "#D3CCC1 |Silver",
               
            }
        ]
    }
];
const items2 = Array.from(new Map(items.reverse().map(item => [item.variants[0].color, item])).values()).reverse();
console.log(items2);
```

Note that `items.reverse()` reverses the original array *in place*. If you need its original order, you would have to call `items.reverse()` again (after creating `items2`).

For every unique color, this approach puts the *first* object into the result, as in your example. If getting the *last* object is also OK, you can remove both `.reverse()` calls from the above code:

```js
Array.from(new Map(items.map(item => [item.variants[0].color, item])).values());
```